# UNION data type mismatch

Tags: sql, ms-access

Running a UNION query in an access database. I've defined every variable as a int since there was a data type mismatch error prompt. This has not resolved the issue. Each of the variables have values of either 1 or 0 and no nulls. Any ideas?

```
SELECT
CInt(qryGB.BM∞) AS [BM∞],
CInt(qryGB.PM∞) AS [PM∞],
CInt(qryGB.P∞) AS [P∞],
CInt(qryGB.[RAG_B<0]) AS [RAG_B<0],
CInt(qryGB.[RAG_P<0]) AS [RAG_P<0],
CInt(qryGB.[RAG_C<0]) AS [RAG_C<0],
CInt(qryGB.[B<0]) AS [B<0],
CInt(qryGB.[P<0]) AS [P<0],
CInt(qryGB.[C<0]) AS [C<0],
CInt(qryGB.[P-1]) AS [P-1],
CInt(qryGB.[C-1]) AS [C-1],
CInt(qryGB.P0) AS [P0],
CInt(qryGB.C0) AS [C0],
CInt(qryGB.[P+1]) AS [P+1],
CInt(qryGB.[P+2]) AS [P+2],
CInt(qryGB.[P+3]) AS [P+3]
FROM qryGB

UNION ALL SELECT
CInt(qryTMD.BM∞) AS [BM∞],
CInt(qryTMD.PM∞) AS [PM∞],
CInt(qryTMD.P∞) AS [P∞],
CInt(qryTMD.[RAG_B<0]) AS [RAG_B<0],
CInt(qryTMD.[RAG_P<0]) AS [RAG_P<0],
CInt(qryTMD.[RAG_C<0]) AS [RAG_C<0],
CInt(qryTMD.[B<0]) AS [B<0],
CInt(qryTMD.[P<0]) AS [P<0],
CInt(qryTMD.[C<0]) AS [C<0],
CInt(qryTMD.[P-1]) AS [P-1],
CInt(qryTMD.[C-1]) AS [C-1],
CInt(qryTMD.P0) AS [P0],
CInt(qryTMD.C0) AS [C0],
CInt(qryTMD.[P+1]) AS [P+1],
CInt(qryTMD.[P+2]) AS [P+2],
CInt(qryTMD.[P+3]) AS [P+3]
FROM qryTMD;
```

Comment: try to remove aliases in the second query

Comment: Does the data type mismatch also occur when executing the query as two separate queries? I expect one of the values not to be numeric and thus resulting in a data type mismatch.

Comment: Nope works fine as separate queries

Comment: Removing the aliases doesn't make any noticeable difference

Comment: if I add a value to 100 to each variable to the individual queries get no error prompt. If I then try to join them then still get the error

Answer (score 1):

Check you don't have any nulls in any of the columns.

Access SQL is a little strange when it comes to nulls (noting that Standard SQL nulls are strange to begin with!). For example you can't cast a null to a data type:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CINT( NULL ) AS null_cast_to_int FROM AnyPopulatedTable;
```

errors with "Invalid use of Null".

So all Access SQL nulls are of the same type but what type?:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TYPENAME ( NULL ) AS type_name FROM  AnyPopulatedTable;
```

does not error and returns 'Null' !!

Comment: It was to do with nulls in the end. Some funny type mixing in a earlier query.

Answer (score 0):

The one thing I can think of is that doing the `CInt()` conversion during the `UNION` may be screwing things up.  I'd try doing the conversion in subqueries before doing the `UNION`.  Something like:

```
SELECT
a.[BM∞],
a.[PM∞],
a.[P∞],
a.[RAG_B<0],
a.[RAG_P<0],
a.[RAG_C<0],
a.[B<0],
a.[P<0],
a.[C<0],
a.[P-1],
a.[C-1],
a.[P0],
a.[C0],
a.[P+1],
a.[P+2],
a.[P+3]
FROM
    (SELECT
    CInt(qryGB.[BM∞]) AS [BM∞],
    CInt(qryGB.[PM∞]) AS [PM∞],
    CInt(qryGB.[P∞]) AS [P∞],
    CInt(qryGB.[RAG_B<0]) AS [RAG_B<0],
    CInt(qryGB.[RAG_P<0]) AS [RAG_P<0],
    CInt(qryGB.[RAG_C<0]) AS [RAG_C<0],
    CInt(qryGB.[B<0]) AS [B<0],
    CInt(qryGB.[P<0]) AS [P<0],
    CInt(qryGB.[C<0]) AS [C<0],
    CInt(qryGB.[P-1]) AS [P-1],
    CInt(qryGB.[C-1]) AS [C-1],
    CInt(qryGB.[P0]) AS [P0],
    CInt(qryGB.[C0]) AS [C0],
    CInt(qryGB.[P+1]) AS [P+1],
    CInt(qryGB.[P+2]) AS [P+2],
    CInt(qryGB.[P+3]) AS [P+3]
    FROM qryGB) as a
UNION ALL SELECT
b.[BM∞],
b.[PM∞],
b.[P∞],
b.[RAG_B<0],
b.[RAG_P<0],
b.[RAG_C<0],
b.[B<0],
b.[P<0],
b.[C<0],
b.[P-1],
b.[C-1],
b.[P0],
b.[C0],
b.[P+1],
b.[P+2],
b.[P+3]
FROM
    (SELECT
    CInt(qryTMD.[BM∞]) AS [BM∞],
    CInt(qryTMD.[PM∞]) AS [PM∞],
    CInt(qryTMD.[P∞]) AS [P∞],
    CInt(qryTMD.[RAG_B<0]) AS [RAG_B<0],
    CInt(qryTMD.[RAG_P<0]) AS [RAG_P<0],
    CInt(qryTMD.[RAG_C<0]) AS [RAG_C<0],
    CInt(qryTMD.[B<0]) AS [B<0],
    CInt(qryTMD.[P<0]) AS [P<0],
    CInt(qryTMD.[C<0]) AS [C<0],
    CInt(qryTMD.[P-1]) AS [P-1],
    CInt(qryTMD.[C-1]) AS [C-1],
    CInt(qryTMD.[P0]) AS [P0],
    CInt(qryTMD.[C0]) AS [C0],
    CInt(qryTMD.[P+1]) AS [P+1],
    CInt(qryTMD.[P+2]) AS [P+2],
    CInt(qryTMD.[P+3]) AS [P+3]
    FROM qryTMD) as b
```

Comment: I did try something like this as well

Comment: @JakeDuddy this one's a long shot: you have a lot of mathematical operators in your varnames. Perhaps Access is trying to do math with them, despite you having the names in `[ ]`.  Maybe try changing the aliases to remove the operators.  So replace `[BM∞]` with `BM_sub_inf`; `[RAG_B<0]` with `[RAG_B_l_zero]`, etc.